# Is this a constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, declaration, construct

I saw this code on internet today:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
  int x;
  int y;
public:
  Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
  Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Test obj1;
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
  obj1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Here see these lines:

```
Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
```

Are setX and setY constructors? If not, what are they? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: They are functions with a return type of `Test`

Comment: No. They are not constructors.

Comment: @Souradeep, just google 'constructors in c++' and check out a link like this one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/

Comment: I presume they were intended to be chainable setters, but the return type ought to be `Test&` in that case.  As they are, they are setters and factory methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class has only one constructor

```
Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; }
```

that is the default constructor because it can be called withoit arguments..

The constructor name is the same as the class.name.

So these

```
  Test setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
```

are two non-static member functions named setX and setY that have one argument of the type int and the return type Test. The functions return copies of the object for which the functions are applied.

So for example this statement

```
obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
```

does not make sense because the call setY is applied to the temporary object returned by the call objq.setX( 10 ).

The methods should be declared at least like

```
  Test & setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
  Test & setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
```

If the functions have the return type Test then this statement

```
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
  obj1.print();
```

produce output

```
x = 10 y = 0
```

If to declare the functions with the return type Test & then the output of the above statements will be

```
x = 10 y = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Below one is the `constructor`(constructor means class name and member function name should be same & it should not have any return type)

```
Test (int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; } /* constructor */
```

`setX` and `setY` are *normal member functions* of the class not the constructor's as just their return types are class-name doesn't make them constructor.

Secondly, If `setX` and `setY` were `constructor` then you don't have to call like `obj1.setX(10).setY(20);` as constructors gets called automatically whenever objects gets created.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors have the name of the class as the method name.

What you have are called *setters*.

Most `setters` return `void`.

Comment: It would be nice if they didn't return void, then they could be used in expressions.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not constructors.

The methods that return 'this' can be chained together, one after the other.

E.g `a.setX (1).setY (2);

Where `a` is an instance of `Test`

Comment: Except that they return copies in this case, making the use of chaining less useful (and more confusing)

Comment: True, but I was looking at the intent.